# Count number of files with specific extension on a folder?

Tags: files, directories

Let's say I'd like to know how many .png images I have in a folder. In shell I'd run:

```
ls -1 | grep .png | wc -l
```

Is there a way to achieve this in emacs (preferably not just reading in from a shell output)?

Comment: After Phils' answer, some doc: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp_Cheat_Sheet#File and https://github.com/rejeep/f.el, for the regexp http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Regexp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```el
(length (directory-files "~/Pictures" nil "\\.png\\'"))
```

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `directory-files`

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to search for both `.png` and `.jpeg`, how would the regex look like? I tried `[(.png)|(.jpeg)]`, but it matches other things too.

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't do what you wanted in any regular expression syntax I've ever seen. As per Ehvince's comment, you should definitely read some documentation. `"\\.\\(png\\|jpeg\\)\\'"` will do the trick in Emacs.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go through the documentation. What I'd tried came from playing with the build-in re-builder

Comment: FYI you could also use the `rx` regexp compiler like so: `(rx "." (or "png" "jpeg") string-end)`

Answer (score 1):

In dired (in directory in which you want to count .png files)
run `M-x eshell-command`:

```
(length (directory-files "" nil "\\.png\\'"))
```